# How to properly remove event listener from window object?

Tags: svelte, web-component, custom-element

**CustomElement.svelte**

```
<svelte:options tag="custom-element" />

<script>
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";

  onMount(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", funcRef);
  });

  onDestroy(() => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", funcRef);
  });

  const funcRef = (event) => {
    doWhatever();
  }
</script>
```

Actually, the event handler should be removed when the custom element gets removed from the document, but it won't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting removed from the document is not the same as getting destroyed. The code of this component [should work as intended](https://svelte.dev/repl/852d75067df144ac8a38e87be075c736?version=3.49.0).

If you use the client-side API or the component lives outside of Svelte's logic (i.e. is not added/removed by another Svelte component, e.g. via `{#if}`), you have to make sure to actually call [`$destroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$destroy).

Comment: I actually thought `onDestroy` was the equivalent of `disconnectedCallback`. So if I remove the custom element outside of a Svelte component, how do I call `$destroy`?

Comment: It is defined as a function of the custom element, so if you have a reference to it, you can just call it like any other function. E.g. `document.querySelector('custom-element').$destroy()`

Comment: Is there another/better way you would recommend?

Comment: Depends on the context, if you can just do everything within Svelte components, and you just have one root component which is never removed anyway, you will not have to deal with this at all. If this is not the case, you will have to dispose the components yourself. Maybe you can leverage some other event to tell you, when `$destroy` has to be called to make this easier. Or you can employ a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to tell you when things get removed.

Answer (score 8):

the code you provided will work properly and it will automatically remove event listeners when the component is destroyed but here is a better version

```js
<svelte:options tag="custom-element" />

<script>
  import { onMount} from "svelte";

  onMount(() => {
    const funcRef = (event) => {
      doWhatever();
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", funcRef);

    return ()=>{
      // this function is called when the component is destroyed
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", funcRef);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is your version better?

Comment: @Annika: It has two advantages: One less import and the event handler does not need to be declared outside the `onMount` to make the scoping work. The impact of this should be fairly minimal though.

Comment: Exactly, that's right @H.B.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```html
<svelte:window
  on:scroll={funcRef}
/>
```

like in this example https://svelte.dev/repl/30667c29ab92487597f7e845578f263a?version=3.52.0